# Нужно ли редактирование?

Tags: редактура

Уважаемые знатоки русского языка, нуждается ли в редактировании такой фрагмент?

> Брат улыбнулся до ушей, а Этайн шагнула к Мидиру.
>
> – Ты решил присоединиться к нам? – обрадовалась она.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне думается, что редактирование не нужно.
Описывается диалог (разговор между двумя или несколькими лицами): общаются, как минимум, Мидир, Этайн и чей-то брат. В ответ на слова Мидира брат улыбнулся, а Этайн шагнула. Далее идет ее реплика с авторскими словами.
С пунктуацией все в порядке.

*Олкисия лишь вздохнула. Конечно, она согласна. Олелф шагнул к Аниклае.

— Отец не против? — юноша приподнял одну бровь.*
(О. Ледоколов. Зелёная скала. История брата и сестры)

*— Я слышала, через два дня обоз с паломниками снова идёт в Иерусалим?

— Да, но сопровождать будем не мы, а госпитальеры.

— Значит, ты останешься? – обрадовалась Франсуаза.* (**1**)
(Ю. Корчевский. Тамплиер. На святой земле)

(**1**). Слова автора начинаются со строчной буквы (***о***брадовалась она; **о**брадовалась Франсуаза), потому что использован глагол, обозначающий чувства говорящего, его ощущения, внутреннее состояние (см. у [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=156)).

**P. S.** Контекста нет — додумываем.
Можно добавить в самом начале авторских слов: на эти слова; в ответ; услышав эти слова; осознав сказанное; услышав признание...